# Link_to with colorbox jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Please tell me what i do wrong. My view:

```
<div id='profile_galery'>       
    <ul>
    <li class='big'><%=link_to image_tag(@profile.user.get_avatar(:large) ), @profile.user.get_avatar(:very_large), :class => 'colorbox'%></li>
```

And my js:

```
  $(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
    $(".colorbox").colorbox();
});
```

But when i click on image it doesnt show - only after page reload it works.

Comment: Do you see any error on browser console?

Comment: oo f... :) yes there is error for other js function . Thanks ! :)

Comment: but now it works only on page reload - and i have $(document).on("ready page:change", function() {

Comment: Honestly never saw that way to attach a handler to `ready` event. Not sure if it's valid or not. Try with `$(document).on("ready", function(){...}` or just `$(function() {...})`